# Pal To Ntsc conversion

Tags: conversion

Hey Guys 
I don't know if you can help, am at the end of a film, ready to send it in to submit for a festival, the festival wants the video in NTSC format and when we did the conversion from pal to ntsc  the sounds pitch went higher, like we expected it to, but I am not sure quite how to fix it, the frame rate was converted from 25fps to 30fps, I did search SSD for this question and it did bring up something it just didn't really help, what i'm asking is there any step by step solution to this using pro tools 9? 
Would really appreciate any help thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're not really going to 30fps...you're going to either 29.97 (or maybe 23.98). I realize you may just be rounding, but who knows what newbies are out there looking at this page? Don't want them to get confused. ;)

Just pitch shift your finished mix by the inverse percentage of the pull-down (i.e. here you're talking about a 4.1% pull-down, so pitch your mix up by 4.1%). If you feel you need step-by-step instructions, [this article might be useful](http://protools.dudesnetwork.com/2009/05/18/audio-pull-updown/). *[Note: The article talks about doing your pull-up/pull-down on import...yes, you can do this on export if you choose to "Bounce" the audio instead of an internal re-record. If you've already made the speed conversion, you don't need to do it again. Don't make the mistake of doing it twice.]*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! I actually asked this question a bit prematurely, was quite frantic trying to problem solve at the time, turned out the picture wasn't acceptable as well after that conversion was far too quick, we originally tried from 25 fps to 29.97, so we then tried 25 fps to 23.98 fps, the sound pitch was better but they     just     spoke     so     slowly, we ended up finding Jes deinterlacer and that converted the entire project picture and sound to ntsc quite successfully. Thanks once again!

Comment: nice. we typically do everything all at once through a hardware converter here. it definitely makes things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Hi! Did your film start as a film at 24fps or a video 25fps PAL? If so the pitch shift is 0.1% and barely noticeable. If you do a PAL 25fps to NTSC 29.97 (running at 23,976) then you will suffer a greater than 4% reduction is speed and pitch. The pitch can be fixed but your music runs slower and your edits will have had the pace taken off them in places. A number of programs can fix the pitch, the speed change requires judicious re-editing, that if your target was cinema in the first place, should have taken place at 24fps not 25fps.
Best, Ray